# MYSQL stops function when no data is found? (node.js)

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am getting som data from my MYSQL database. It checks for the email and date to match the users email and chosen date, then it gets the matching rows data. It all works well if I use a date that exists in the table, but when I use a date that does not exists, I get a ER_PARSE_ERROR.

It looks like this:

```
    let date = 27/09/2019

        let sql = `SELECT weigh, temp, length, cat, date FROM reps WHERE email = 'test@gmail.com' AND date = ?`;
        connection.query(sql, [date], (error, result, fields) => { 
          if (error) throw error;
//here I do some stuff
```

When the date is not in the database, I get this:

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')'
```

If there is no date, it now crashes my whole function. Instead I just want it to not get anything and keep the function going.

I tried below but it is still crashing:

```
 if (error) {
send.response('nothing');
}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: "*When the date is not in the database, I get this*" the error suggests your SQL is wrong, not that the date is not there. Not having specific data doesn't throw an error but just returns an empty dataset.

Comment: maybe you are passing undefined as date variable and your sql became invalid. try to add a check on variable before executing query

Comment: @VLAZ when i choose a date that is in the database, i get the dataset without any errors. When the date is not there, it gives me the parse error, not an empty dataset

Comment: @JackTurky sorry but the date variable is valid, i tried to console.log it before and it is showing the correct date.

Comment: What is the type for your field `date`? If it is `timestamp`, `datetime`, or `date` you need to provide your value in the correct format of `YYYY-MM-DD`. Additionally if you're using `timestamp` of `datetime` you need to scope your query to include all times for that date: `... AND DATE(date) = ?`. In your example your `date` variable should be a `string` (enclosed by quotes or ticks), since it is not cast as `string` it will resolve as a mathematical function and (in this example at least) date will equal `0.0014858841`

Answer (score 0):

This is finally solved. The reason I got the ER_PARSE_ERROR: was because I hade some functions that relied on the MySQL output. When no rows from MySQL was shown, the error occurred. I solved it by saying if nothing then end response. This is the code:

```
if (error) { throw error;
} else if (!result.length) {  //Checks if no results, then ends the response without doing anything, before it tried to do things when there was no result which caused the error.                                          
    return console.log('Date or email does not match any database rows');
    response.end();
  }
```